# Display Show List when Value selected in Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

]I would like a dashboard worksheet that has a text box listing the string value of a particular cell in each worksheet in a workbook, but only if that cell matches a specific value.

Scenario: I have a spreadsheet where each worksheet represents a 'show' name, and inside that sheet are the details for the show, including a cell displaying the 'genre', e.g. whether it's 'cabaret, youth, circus, play, etc'

My dashboard sheet currently displays all of the 'genres' in column A, and the number of shows per genre (dynamically updated)

I want to have a text box to the right of this which will dynamically list the show names (per worksheet) matching a particular genre depending on the cell selected in column A (as in the attached picture)

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated!

[Where I want the text list displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we9IK.png)

[The 'show' sheets from where the data is referenced, cells C6 and C8 respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSZgU.png)

Comment: Since you are looking for automation short of action like if you select A2 value the related shows must display in column C,, in that case it needs VBA(MAcro), are you comfortable with it ? If yes then first edit the OP and add VBA Tag. Also edit the Title like, "Display Show List when Value selected in Cell."

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, I've edited the request as you suggested.

Comment: Soon I'll post the solution ☺

Comment: Thank you so much. If it helps, the 'show name' in each worksheet is always in the same cell.

Comment: Your Workbook has a sheet for the Show name along with Genre and other, since are  scattered across sheets   so to club them as per Genre is somewhat tedious coz there is no set patter of data to be extracted. Formula need a perfect architecture of data set to handle. Better share the Workbook if    possible. since I've to workout with other infos too. Meanwhile I would like to suggest you to create Master sheet like I did to filter Shows. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to suggest you simple & easier solution will extracts all the Show Names related to the Genre:**

*I've assumed the below shown data as Source Values:*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. In Cell `D150` create a *Drop Down* using **Data Validation**.
2. Add Genre name *Aborginal* & *Children* to Drop Down.

*Write following array formula in `D152` finish with `Ctrl+shift+Enter` & Fill down.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$150:$B$155,SMALL(IF($A$150:$A$155=D$150,ROW($B$150:$B$155)-MIN(ROW($B$150:$B$155))+1),ROWS($D$152:D152))),"")}
```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, I see where you're going with that, and it is helpful.
My data though in the two cells for 'showname' and 'genre' is spread over an ever increasing number of worksheets, one per show. I will attach another screenshot to show this....

Comment: @KevinD, sure either you attach the genuine data Sheet or share with us on cloud ☺

Comment: I've included links to two screenshots now with an edit. The reference cells to use are always C6 and C8

Comment: You can find my mail Id on the profile page, and let me check the links, you also try the solution I've given, on the data .

Comment: @KevinD, soon I'll return to your MBOx. ☺

Comment: I'm guessing the code would refer to something along the lines of:
"If a worksheet called DashBoard has a particular cell selected which indicates a genre name, then for each "show" worksheet, (and where the 'genre' cell value matches the selected 'genre' value on the dashboard sheet), then list the value of the cell pertaining to the show name" in a text box on the DashBoard worksheet." (referring to the first screenshot I've attached)

Comment: @KevinD, glad to help you, keep asking. ☺